# Custom Validation doesn't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Here are my lines of code:

For the `Textbox` and the `CustomValidator`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Edit_Tbox_Email" runat="server" placeholder="Email Address..." CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="submission"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Edit_Tbox_Email" ID="cv_Email" OnServerValidate="cv_Email_ServerValidate" ErrorMessage="!" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Invalid Input!" ValidationGroup="submission"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

This is for the `Button` to allow the user to change his/her email:

```
<asp:Button ID="Edit_But_Email" runat="server" Text="Change" CssClass="btn btn-small" OnClick="Edit_But_Email_Click" ValidationGroup="submission" CausesValidation="true"/>
```

On server side:

```
protected void Edit_But_Email_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Page.IsValid)
            Edit_Lab_Email.Text = Edit_Tbox_Email.Text;
    }

protected void cv_Email_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        string emailRegex = "^\\w+[\\w-\\.]*\\@\\w+((-\\w+)|(\\w*))\\.[a-z]{2,3}$";
        if (Edit_Tbox_Email.Text.Length == 0 || Regex.IsMatch(Edit_Tbox_Email.Text, emailRegex))
        {
            cv_Email.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
```

But the problem here is that `cv_Email_ServerValidate()` doesn't even fire. Basically, it doesn't validate the `Textbox`. Also, I don't want to use the `RequiredFieldValidator` and `RegularExpressionValidator`. I want to combine their functionalities into just one validator. And as much as possible I would like to use the code behind(c#) only and not by jQuery. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button have a `ValidationGroup` but your `CustomValidator` don't have one. If you want your button to valide it, you must set the same `ValidationGroup`.

***Edit:***
You have to set `ValidateEmptyText="true"` otherwise, it won't validate empty value.

Comment: Actually I already have `ValidationGroup` for all of them but still no luck. I probably copied the wrong code. Sorry for that.